# why do we have a super function if we can call the original bass class function with an instance of the bass class?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, super

Why do we need to use `super(drived_class, self)` if `bass_class()`can does the same job ,What does the super function exactly do?
I have wore some code trying to find out but didn't got a lot.
What is `<super: <class 'b'>, <b object>>` ? And is there any reason for it to take self as the second parameter unlike any other function.

```
>>>class a(object):
...    def somefunc(self):
...        print("af function")
>>>class b(a):
...    def somefunc(self):
...        print("overriding af")
...    def recalling_bassclass_somefunc(self):
...        print("////")
...        print("recalling it via super func")
...        super(b,self).somefunc()
...        print("recalling it via super func with b() instead of self")
...        super(b,b()).somefunc()
...        print("recalling it via an a class object")
...        print(a().somefunc)
...        print("printing the a class")
...        print(a())
...        print("printing a type")
...        print(type(a()))
...        print("printing the super(b,self)")
...        print(super(b,self))
...        print("printing the super(b,self) type")
...        print(type(super(b,self)))
...        print(type(a()) == type(super(b,self)))
...        print(a() == super(b,self))
...a().somefunc()
...b().somefunc()
...b().recalling_bassclass_somefunc()
af function
overriding af
////
recalling it via super func
af function
recalling it via super func with b() instead of self
af function
recalling it via an a class object
<bound method a.somefunc of <__main__.a object at 0x00000201DCD207F0>>
printing the a class
<__main__.a object at 0x00000201DCCED748>
printing a type
<class '__main__.a'>
printing the super(b,self)
<super: <class 'b'>, <b object>>
printing the super(b,self) type
<class 'super'>
False
False
```

Comment: This code keeps creating new (and irrelevant) instances of `a`.

Comment: Hello Hussein, and welcome to SO. I suggest you read a good tutorial on object-oriented programming in Python - there are plenty of excellent online tutorials. try https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/ for starters.